# how to build JS library from Typescript with webpack

Tags: javascript, typescript, webpack

I create a library project structure as below:

[image]

This is package.json

```
{
  "name": "testlib",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "library for test",
  "scripts": {
    "build:dev": "webpack --mode development",
    "build:prod": "webpack --mode production",
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "ts-loader": "^9.4.4",
    "typescript": "^5.1.6",
    "webpack": "^5.88.2",
    "webpack-cli": "^5.1.4"
  }
}
```

This tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es6",
    "module": "es6",
    "outDir": "./dist",
    "sourceMap": true
  },
  "include": ["src"],
  "exclude": ["node_modules"]
}
```

This is webpack.config.js

```
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
    entry: './src/index.ts',
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.ts$/,
                loader: 'ts-loader',
                include: [path.resolve(__dirname, 'src')]
            }
        ]
    },
    resolve: {
        extensions: ['.ts', '.js']
    },
    output: {
        filename: 'testlib.js',
        library: 'testlib',
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist')
    }
}
```

This is index.ts

```
console.log('load test-lib index.ts');

export function myTestLib() {
    console.log('myTestLib function');
}

export {Sample1} from './Sample/sample1';
```

This is the generated testlib.js

```js
var testlib;(()=>{"use strict";var e={d:(o,t)=>{for(var l in t)e.o(t,l)&&!e.o(o,l)&&Object.defineProperty(o,l,{enumerable:!0,get:t[l]})},o:(e,o)=>Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(e,o),r:e=>{"undefined"!=typeof Symbol&&Symbol.toStringTag&&Object.defineProperty(e,Symbol.toStringTag,{value:"Module"}),Object.defineProperty(e,"__esModule",{value:!0})}},o={};e.r(o),e.d(o,{Sample1:()=>t,myTestLib:()=>l});class t{constructor(){console.log("this is sample 1")}}function l(){console.log("myTestLib function")}console.log("load test-lib index.ts"),testlib=o})();
```

Is this testlib.js is correct? I checked the tutorial video, their generated *.js file is different with me. The main difference is the webpack version, typescript version, ts-loader version. Others I followed the tutorial to set up these configurations.

If i import the testlib.js in my angular project.

```
import * as testLib from '../../../libs/testlib';
console.log(this.tag + 'awcLib function:', testLib.myTestLib());
```

It has error:

> TypeError: *libs_testlib__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_8*_.myTestLib is not
> a function

Finally I solved by below for my reusable library

```
library: {
    name: "testLib",
    type: "umd"
},
globalObject: "this",
```

Comment: Please do not post images of your code and/or error messages. **Post the actual text instead.** This makes it easier for people to help you and for others to find this question in a search if they have similar issues in the future. Please read over the answers to this question to understand a bit more about this: [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: @ChrisBarr I modified it. Thanks a lot for your info.

Answer (score 1):

This is the normal behaviour when Webpack renames function names when it uglifies the code.

`testLib.myTestLib()` is unknown afterwards.

You can see this in the minified output (`function l` instead of `function myTestLib`):

```
function l(){console.log("myTestLib function")}console.log("...
```

The `window` object is not changed. You can attach your method to this object and then access it.

```
import { myTestLib } from '../../../libs/testlib';

window.testLib = {
  myTestLib
};

console.log(this.tag + 'awcLib function:', testLib.myTestLib());
```

Comment: If i don't want to uglifies the code, then I cannot use webpack?

Comment: Of course. You can deactivate it. Try `minify: false` in webpacks `output{...}` section.

Comment: i solved this by using export library type pr libraryTarget